# Advance Vegetation Index

Tags: google-earth-engine

I want to run this expression; Note that it should be raised to power1/3. 
'[Band5*(256-Band4)*(Band5-Band4)+1]"^"(1/3)',  {

And I'm getting this error;
Image.parse Expression: Expression parse error at character 0:
'[Band5*(256-Band4)*(Band5-Band4)+1]"^"(1/3)'
 ^.
Is my expression correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the expression language of `Image.expression`, exponentiation is `**`, not `^`, and you cannot use square brackets for grouping, only parentheses. So, your expression would be written as

```
image.expression('(Band5 * (256-Band4) * (Band5-Band4) + 1) ** (1/3)', {
  'Band5': ...,
  'Band4': ...
})
```